# Is there a word for "to make humble" with a positive connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

The word "humiliate" carries very negative connotations; is there a verb for "making someone humble" or "giving someone humility" in a positive way?

For instance, "Having children of my own *humiliated* me" isn't the best choice of words.

Comment: If I may monologue, I like to think of _humiliate_ as someone else thrusting humility onto an unwilling target, hence the negative connotation.

Comment: Also consider *enlightened*. Not *humble* based but conveys a new perspective.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the verb [*humble*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/humble) is at least more neutral than *humiliate*, although the connotation might not be specifically positive.

Some examples via [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) from various sources:

> That's the sign that little Melipona, messenger of the gods, has been trying to deliver all along. The missive is so literal, I can't help but feel **humbled** - and connected. The message is simple and sweet.
>
> It's so amazing to have my name on a list with these other women. I feel very **humbled** by it. I just feel honored.

I don't think these examples carry the negative connotation that *humiliate* does.

Comment: Beware though, *humiliated* is one of the meanings of *humbled* used exactly the same way in some contexts.

Comment: @Kris Hence neutral rather than specifically positive, as I said.

Comment: No way. It gets the connotation from the context.

Comment: @Kris Yep.  That's what neutral means: it's neither negative nor positive itself.

Comment: *He was humbled at the stakes* has the same connotation has *He got drubbing at the stakes.* HTH. So never use *humble* where the context is as clear as in the OP's sentence.

Comment: I didn't think of the fact that you could use _humble_ as a verb.

Comment: @Kris - _humbled_ is neutral, dependent on context, and <b>the</b> perfect word here: parenting is a humbling experience. Have you any children? If you do, and are not humbled by the experience, you must be a perfect parent. Positive context: _I am humbled by your kindness._ Negative context: _I was humbled by my poor performance._ Neutral (but hopeful): _Parenting is a humbling experience._

Comment: @Susan May you have some more nice children.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a slight variation on *humiliate* -

> "Having children of my own *gave me a new **humility***."

While they both come from the same Latin roots, **[humiliate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/humiliate)** now means

> to hurt the pride or dignity of by causing to be or seem foolish or contemptible; mortify

but **[humility](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/humility)** means

> the state or quality of being humble; absence of pride or self-assertion

This is not a negative connotation, but neutral to positive.

Comment: You say it "humiliate now means". Do you know if it carried a different connotation in the past?

Comment: @IQAndreas Both words come from Latin roots for *humble*. To make humble is much less negative than humiliate (which implies shame). I temporalized it simply because I don't know how it was used in the 19th, 18th, 17th centuries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for a meaning along the lines of being less accepting, less harsh or strident, or more mature or developed, you could consider **mellowed**, **matured**, or **softened**. These are all positive attributes.

"Having children of my own **softened** me."

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... I suppose it depends on the exact sentence it is being used in, but a *possible* replacement might be "enlighten" Both 'humble' and 'humiliate' usually occur when information is revealed or someone learns something; for example, you might be humbled when you learn a friend gave a bunch of his paycheck to cover your rent when he knew your budget was tight, or you might be humiliated when you learn your coworkers are talking behind your back.

On the other hand, if you learn something that betters you, like the 'having children' example you gave, you could call yourself 'enlightened' instead.

Hope that is useful to you.

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard neither 'humble' nor 'humiliate' used that way. Both words have to do with pride (see the definitions posted in [@bib's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/143229/5438)).